# Powerpivot one to many filter column

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have 2 tables, a visit table and then a diagnosis table. Visit is my one and diagnosis is my many (you can have secondary and tertiary diagnosis).
I have over 50 measures created in the visit table. Because of this, I simply want to create a flag on my visit table in the form of a column that will filter down my results based upon selections from the Diagnosis table. I have seen formulas for measures that use =calculate([cases],DXCodes) which will filter down the cases to only those that relate to the DXCodes and this works, but I don't want to have to build this in for every measure. Instead I want a DXFlag that will flag my visit rows with a 1 if what I selected from Diagnosis exists in the Visit table. Suggestions? I can get more specific if this is not making sense

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a calculation that will return a 1 against any visit where either the primary, secondary or tertiary diagnosis matches with one of the currently selected diagnosis/diagnoses? Do you have a column in your visit table for each of these diagnosis fields? You have mentioned not wanting to have to modify every measure - did you want all your existing measures to return zero (or blank) values if the visit was not flagged with a 1? I'm just trying to understand why you want a column, rather than a measure.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about your data, you could have tables like this:
[image]

And if you create a measure to pick out each of the diagnoses:

```
[diag1]:=FIRSTNONBLANK(Visits[Primary Diag],1)
[diag2]:=FIRSTNONBLANK(Visits[Secondary Diag],1)
[diag3]:=FIRSTNONBLANK(Visits[Tertiary Diag],1)
```

Then add this measure to flag your visit rows:

```
[Found]:=MAXX(ALLSELECTED(Diagnoses[Diagnosis]),IF(FIRSTNONBLANK(Diagnoses[Diagnosis],1)=[Diag1]||FIRSTNONBLANK(Diagnoses[Diagnosis],1)=[Diag2]||FIRSTNONBLANK(Diagnoses[Diagnosis],1)=[Diag3],1,BLANK()))
```

This gives you this result:

[image]

**Edit: Response to revised/clarified requirements**

I've been trying to see if I can get a calculated column to take account of the diagnosis selection with little success. Doing it with a measure is fairly straightforward:

```
[Diag Flag]:=IF(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DiagnosisTable),FIRSTNONBLANK(DiagnosisTable[Diagnosis],1))>0,1)
```

But this approach would require you to revise all the measures you wish to appear on your output summary. If it's just the total number of visits and the sum of the length of stay, that's not difficult, but if you need to revise all 50 measures it's a bit less appealing.

Here are the new measures for the number of visits and the length of stay which I have shown in a separate PivotTable on the same sheet:

```
[Cases]:=SUMX('Visits',[Diag Flag])
[LengthSum]:=SUMX('Visits',Visits[Length of Stay]*[Diag Flag])
```

And the output:

[image]

NOTE: My slicer is connected to both tables.

Comment: I edited the question with an example of the tables I have along with the answer I am expecting. The Diag Flag is the formula I am looking to create but cannot figure it out. Also, I cannot pivot out the diagnosis onto the Visit table because there can be an exponential amount of diagnosis (yes some patients can have up to 30 or more).